# How to get data from my hosting in android

Tags: android, rest

I have a database and have hosted it also. i need to work with that database in android app . that database contains including images. how to do this? 
i have seen REST API , android PHP/MYSQL connections .
which one is easier? i'm new for android !

Comment: You need some kind of server running to communicate with Android app. REST API servers are generally implemented using php, python, java or node.js. REST API is not an alternative to any of these.

Comment: thank you , is there any simple way other than REST?

Comment: to continue @SarveshKumarSingh comment, you have to first : write your REST API in the language your prefer, depending on your skill (Php is a good solution, Node.js is faster), next you will have rest endpoint which return you json, so retrieve it and parse it in Android using Retrofit for example

Comment: Well... REST is set of guidelines to create simple and well designed API's. I think it will be easiest with REST, you can find lots of good tutorials by Googling.

Comment: Depending of your database, you will have a lot of work to do to build your API and use it in Android.